# OpenCV BGR2RGB Conversion via numpy slicing/stride

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to learn OpenCV and I am new to these things(Python, OpenCV).

Here is the link that i am following [And here is the part i don't understand](https://youtu.be/P4Z8_qe2Cu0?t=681)

In lesson 1. There is a subject about why we should use RGB and BGR conversion. I understand that matplotlib is using RGB and OpenCV is using BGR (Correct me if i'm wrong). But couldn't get how to convert BGR to RGB with this code:

```
coke_img_channels_reversed = coke_img[:, :, ::-1]

plt.imshow(coke_img_channels_reversed)
```

And I couldn't tell if the transformation is done exactly in matrix or array.
How this code change order of BGR to RGB. Can anyone explain it mathematically or logically?

Comment: This isn't specific to images; see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: The last channel dimension of the array is the color channel. If the first dimension were color channel it would be coke_img[::-1, :, :]

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren To be clear it's reversing array's channel dimension but in that channel there are matrices like:
[(140),
(150),
(145),
(random values depends on color intensity)] 
With 3 column. And ::-1 is just reversing columns not the array or matrices values order.
Am i right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of color channels in the last dimension, think of it like this: you have three matrices B (mxn), G (mxn), and R (mxn) that are "stacked" on top of each other with B at the bottom, G in the middle, and R on top. If they were truly separate matrices you would stack them in numpy like this

```
bgr_image = np.concatenate((B[:, :, None], G[:, :, None], R[:, :, None]), axis=2)
```

When you are doing the operation

```
rgb_image = bgr_image[:, :, ::-1]
```

you are flipping that BGR stack so that now R is on bottom, G in the middle, and B on top. From the perspective of array operation (the slice notation): bgr_image[:, :, ::-1] is all the "rows" (dim0) of the bgr_image, all the "columns" (dim1) of the bgr_image, and in the "channels" (dim2) take the last channel first and build back one-by-one all the way to the first channel (effectively reversing the channel order from BGR to RGB). The operation could be rewritten more explicitly as

```
rgb_image = bgr_image[0::1, 0::1, -1::-1]
```

or if you wanted to go way too far in explicitness you could do

```
m, n, c = bgr_image.shape
rgb_image = bgr_image[0:m:1, 0:n:1, -1::-1]
```

OpenCV just makes it a convenience function even though the operation is simple. They also try to mirror the C++ library pretty close, where in C++ the matrix shifting is not quite a simple and the BGRtoRGB function is pretty convenient.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clear explanation!